# Shared mutex between process

Tags: process, operating-system, pthreads, ipc, mutex

I am learning mutex usage between process. I have a question w.r.t this.

Since each process has its own address space, the mutex defined by one process cannot be seen by another. On googling, I came across usage of pthread_mutex_setpshared() to get this done. I am attaching my code below. But looks like even now, the mutex is not shared between processes. How is this to be modified.

I know this can be achieved using named semaphore. But want to know the usage using mutex.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int ch = 0;
    //sem_t *s1;
    //s1 = sem_open("/sem", O_CREAT, 0666, 0);
    pthread_mutex_t m1;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&m1, &attr);
    
    
    pid = fork();
    
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        printf("\nChild process");
        
        printf("\nPress 1 to unlock from child:");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        
        if(ch == 1)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        }
        //sem_post(s1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        //sem_wait(s1);
        printf("\nParent process");
        
        printf("\nPress 2 to unlock from parent:");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        
        if(ch == 2)
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        
        printf("\nError");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as setting the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute, you need to arrange to have the mutex itself (your `m1` variable) stored in shared memory, accessible by both processes.  A duplicate, as created by your `fork()`, does not work.

If you use `mmap()` to create an anonymous mapping with the `MAP_SHARED` flag, and allocate the mutex within that, then it will be shared between the processes after the `fork()` and will work.